# Ubuntu 19.10 installer crashed

Tags: crash, 19.10

Tried to install Ubuntu 19.10, side-by-side with Windows 10 (dual boot). Installer got crashed midway through to the installation

[image: Screenshot of crash]

A fake Installation Complete window popped up, but 'Restart Now' button was not clickable.

Comment: Firstly I'd suggest validating your download, and then do the same for your install media. I see a lot of *squashfs* errors for 'install crashed' bugs (ie. https://tutorials.ubuntu.com/tutorial/tutorial-how-to-verify-ubuntu#0 and https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/CDIntegrityCheck).   I suspect it wasn't a *fake* pop-up, though if it was, I'd blame *squashfs* errors as cause (ie. user failed to validate ISO or write-to-install-media)

Comment: Thanks, @guiverc. I validated the ISO checksum before creating a bootable usb. As suggested, will recreate the bootable media and see if it works.

Comment: Which graphics card do you have?